# How to redirect from the values of DropDownList using SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm having a problem with redirecting the page to the another one according to the selectedvalue from dropdownlist.

I can list categories in the dropdownlist using SQL Server.

```
namespace Deneme
{
    public class Baglanti
    {
        public SqlConnection Baglanma()
        {
            //integrated security windows auth için.
            SqlConnection baglan = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-IB3QGLL;Database=Sports;Integrated Security = True");
            baglan.Open();
            SqlConnection.ClearPool(baglan);
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
            return (baglan);
        }
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand komut2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT clubid,club_name FROM kulupler", baglan.Baglanma());
    SqlDataReader reader  = komut2.ExecuteReader();
baglan.Baglanma();

    DDLProduct.DataSource = reader;
    DDLProduct.DataValueField = "clubid";
    DDLProduct.DataTextField = "club_name";
    DDLProduct.DataBind();
}

protected void BtnGonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Category.aspx?ID="+DDLProduct.SelectedValue);
}
```

Product:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLProduct" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:button id="BtnGonder" runat="server" text="Gönder" OnClick="BtnGonder_Click">
</asp:button>
```

I can list all the categories in the dropdown list. When I click the button it's always goes to `Category.aspx?ID=1` which is the value of the first element of the dropdownlist.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dtblItemList = new DataTable();
  using (SqlConnection conn = DataExecutor.GetSqlConnection()){
   conn.Open();
   SqlCommand komut2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT clubid,club_name FROM 
                       kulupler", conn);
   //SqlDataReader reader  = komut2.ExecuteReader();
   using(SqlDataReader reader = DataExecutor.GetSqlDataReader(komut2, 
        CommandBehavior.Default))
                            {
                                dtblItemList.Load(reader);
                            }      
    }

  DDLProduct.DataSource = dtblItemList;
  DDLProduct.DataValueField = "clubid";
  DDLProduct.DataTextField = "club_name";
  DDLProduct.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Cannot recognize DataExecutor